# Split data into 2 equal halves

Tags: python, statistics

Let's say my table of data looks like this :

| Entity_Id | Attribute_1 | Attribute_2 | Attribute_3 | Attribute_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| entity_1 | value_1a | value_2a | value_3a | value_4a |
| entity_2 | value_1b | value_2b | value_3b | value_4b |
| emtity_3 | value_1c | value_2c | value_3c | value_4c |
| entity_4 | value_1a | value_2d | value_3d | value_4d |
| ' | ' | ' | ' | ' |
| ' | ' | ' | ' | ' |

I need to split this data into 2 halves, i.e; each half would contain equal number of 'Entities'.

But the split should be so that these two halves should be identical in terms of their *Attributes*.  The distribution of each of the attributes should be similar in both the halves.

Basically I need to split a single table of data into two statistically similar halves.

Appreciate any help, preferably using Python.

Comment: What if the distribution of one attribute is different from another attribute, so you can't be equal in both?

Comment: I am looking for the best possible split. Most probably perfect split is not possible, but I am looking for as identical split as possible.

Comment: What statistics of the attributes are you talking about? Mean/median/mode value, standard deviation, etc.?

Comment: Mean and Variance.